# How can I create mosaico block with 2 button?

Tags: civimail, mosaico, templates, custom-templates, flexmailer

I would need a mosaico block with 2 button, is it possible to create? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer for how to create a new block, but if you need something quick and dirty with two buttons side-by-side, hold your nose for this horrible hack...

- Drag over a "Two-Columns Block".
- Change to Block Level Style so you don't mess up other blocks.
- Change the Paragraph Size to the smallest (or use the instructions in the next section).
- Disable "Show Title" and "Show Image".
- Remove the text from both columns.

If you want to minimize the blank text areas:

- Select one of the text areas.
- Choose the Source Code option ("<>").
- Substitute a placeholder: `<p style="color:transparent;font-size:1px;">&thinsp;</p>`
- Repeat for the other text area.

Unfortunately, there are no options for aligning the buttons or making them different colors, but at least you'll have a two button block to butt up against other blocks.

Notes:

1. I'm assuming you are using the Versafix-1 template.
2. I found that I had to use something other than an actual space character (or `&nbsp;`) for the text areas. Otherwise, the source code block wasn't saved the next time I tried to edit it. I could leave some transparent text, but I don't want to impact someone using a screen reader.
3. You might be able to use "font-size:0" to completely eliminate the text area but I doubt you'll be able to select it again since there is no substance left for the editor to represent.